# Explanation of distribution solution.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-explanation

[image]

[image]

Above is the picture of the question  and below, the answer. Could someone please explain how in the solution we have P(U<=a) = P([1-a,1])? How did we get the P([1-a,1])? and in the equation line, how did we get E(U) = integral of xdx? From what I know, the formula of E(X) is integral of x*(f(x)). So how does that formula fit here in this integral? Where is the f(x) here? Help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Instead of posting pictures, you should transcribe the images into MathJax. This makes it so that people can search $E[U\cos(U/n)]$ in [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/), and have your question come up.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a guide; it may look large and daunting, but typing in mathjax is mostly as simple as enclosing your equation in `$`'s, and then when that is not enough, looking at the reference to figure out the particular thing you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $P(U\le a)$ is shorthand for $P(\{\omega\in\Omega: U(\omega)\le a\})$. And by definition of $\Omega$ and $U$, we have
$$\{\omega\in\Omega: U(\omega)\le a\}=\{\omega\in(0,1]: 1-\omega\le a\}
==\{\omega\in(0,1]: \omega\ge 1-a\}=[1-a,1].
$$
Hence the event $(U\le a)$ is the same as the interval $[1-a,1]$.

As for the assertion
$$E(U)=\int_0^1 x\,dx,$$ we know that $U$ has a uniform$(0,1)$ distribution and therefore the density of $U$ is
$$
f(x):=\begin{cases}1&0<x\le 1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.
$$ Substitute this $f$ into the formula $$E(U)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)\,dx$$ to obtain the result.

Comment: Could you please explain the reasoning behind this: $\{\omega\in\Omega: U(\omega)\le a\}=\{\omega\in(0,1]: 1-\omega\le a\}$? How did $U(\omega)$ become$ 1-\omega$?

Comment: As stated, $U:\Omega\to{\mathbb R}$, $\omega\to1-\omega$. This is saying that $U$ maps $\omega$ to $1-\omega$, therefore $U(\omega)=1-\omega$.